# Not so sticky vinyl for branding

Tags: print-design, vinyl

I hope this is the right place. Tried Area52 for "printing" but that site is not launched yet.

I have a "non sticky" situation where I need to be able to stick a model number down of a product to farming equipment but that must come off relatively easily when that product is upgraded.

At the moment they are using vinyl decals which withstands the conditions of farming but is incredibly difficult to remove when they need to update the model number.

I have spoken to multiple printers in our area and there has been no ideal solution to sort this out.

The stickers are applied to panels of 1.5m by 250mm. We have tried a PVC glove but these get stolen (the same as magnetic decals). Another solution would be to mount it on a separate panel and "this" panel is then mounted onto the main panel but we're also trying to keep costs down.

If someone knows of a sticker that will stick in farming conditions but that will come off relatively easily I would appreciate it.

Comment: Small metal or plastic plate with a single screw to hold it in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you want something durable for outdoor condition and something easy to remove. It doesn't really work that way. Anything easy to remove won't stand up to harsh environments.

There are Static Films you can print on, but even that won't hold up very well outside. Here's a nice comparison of Vinyl Decals and Static Clings: http://www.signazon.com/vinyl-decal-vs-static-cling.aspx

While I'm not sure why you need to update the model number that frequently two solutions that come to mind:

1. Direct heat source greatly helps removing vinyl adhesives. In absence of a professional heat gun used by a decal shop a hair dryer can be used.
2. Alternatively you can print the model number on a smaller decal similar to a vehicle tag that just gets stacked on top of the old one.

Comment: Many thanks Ryan. I am not a print designer (web) and landed this that I cannot say no to it. What do you mean by option 2. if you don't mind me asking? You mean you just stick over the entire last sticker?

Comment: @SixfootJames yeah. Not sure if you're American or not so maybe my example didn't make sense. But yes basically print the model on a smaller vinyl decal and when you need to update, just drop a new one on top. Its industrial equipment so it shouldn't be a huge issue.

Comment: Actually, that is going to work like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with a similar problem now (7 years later ;)  Photo Tex self-adhesive fabric could work. https://phototexgroup.com/products/

One of the waterproof or High Tack versions may suit your need.

If it needs to be coated, you could try a Marabu liquid coating.

Both might send you a sample to test.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE rick42! Nice to see this question answered. Could you edit your answer to specify if you are affiliated to Photo Tex as required by our spam guidelines?